# Trying to understand the difference between git repos and vss database

Tags: visual-studio, git, visual-sourcesafe

I've been a Visual SourceSafe user for years and for obvious reasons I'm trying to make the change to git.  I've downloaded and have been trying the git extensions for Visual Studio 2012.  I have a few questions that I hope someone can help me with.

Using the git extension, when I add my VS solution to source control it creates a git repository in the directory where my project is stored.  With VSS I'm accustomed to all of my projects residing in the same repository.  With git, it seems that I get a repository per project/solution.  Is this typical or am I doing something wrong?

Also, when I have a solution with multiple projects and I add source control, the main project is added to a git repository (again, it's own repository) but the referenced projects do not get included...I have to then add them to source control individually, again they get their own repo in their corresponding project folder.

So with git is there a repository per project rather than a repository that holds multiple projects?

Is there a resource available to help VSS users make the mental shift to git?  A git for dummies (er, vss users) video/blog/book would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems natural to have one git repository per VS solution.  For one thing, it's much easier to remove an old deprecated solution if it has its own repo.  But git supports both: you can have one big repository with multiple solutions too.

[This site is worth doing](http://gitimmersion.com/) as an introduction.  For much more detailed information, you can download [the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book).

Learning git is not easy, and using git is definitely more complex than using Visual SourceSafe.  But it's very much worth it.